# Unable to use access="permitAll"

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security

I am using spring 4 and hibernate 5.

Below is the xml config for my spring security.

I have this line:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/android/download"          access="permitAll" />
```

When i tried access from SOAPUI, all i get is

```
Authentication request failed: com.test.common.JwtTokenMissingException: No token found in request headers. Please login again!
com.test.common.JwtTokenMissingException: No token found in request headers. Please login again!
```

Is there something wrong with my config file? I do not wish to set to `security="none"` as i want it to go through spring security.

Could it be the order in which the authenication is done in my *CustomAuthenticationFilter* class?

XML file for spring security:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <sec:http auto-config="false" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="customEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**"                  access="hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('MANAGER') or hasRole('SUPERVISOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/agent/**"                  access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/analysis/**"               access="hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('MANAGER') or hasRole('SUPERVISOR') or hasRole('IC') or hasRole('OPS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/android/download"          access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/android/**"                access="hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('SNF_AGENT')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/audit/**"                  access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/auth/logout"               access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/external/**"               access="hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('MANAGER') or hasRole('SUPERVISOR') or hasRole('SV_IC') or hasRole('IC') " />
        <intercept-url pattern="/index.xhtml"               access="hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('MANAGER') or hasRole('SUPERVISOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/misc/**"                   access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/mission/missions/search"   access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/mission/**"                access="hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('MANAGER') or hasRole('SUPERVISOR') or hasRole('SV_IC')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/report/**"                 access="hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('MANAGER') or hasRole('SUPERVISOR')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/request/**"                access="hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('MANAGER') or hasRole('SUPERVISOR') or hasRole('IC') or hasRole('OPS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/target/**"                 access="hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('MANAGER') or hasRole('SUPERVISOR') or hasRole('IC')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/trawling/**"               access="hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('MANAGER') or hasRole('SUPERVISOR')" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/**"                        access="denyAll" />     

        <sec:custom-filter ref="customAuthenticationFilter"
            before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />

        <sec:csrf disabled="true" />

    </sec:http>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationFilter"
        class="com.test.common.CustomAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            ref="customSuccessHandler" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="customSuccessHandler" class="com.test.common.CustomSuccessHandler" />

</beans:beans>
```

/**EDITED **/

I missed out this portion of code for **CustomAuthenticationFilter** class:

```
@Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        String header = request.getHeader(this.tokenHeader);

        if (request.getServletPath().contains(".xhtml"))
        {
            header = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("token");
        }

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(PropertiesUtil.TOKEN_HEADER))
        {
            throw new JwtTokenMissingException(msgProperty.getProperty(MessageUtil.ERR_AUTH_NO_TOKEN));
        }

        String authToken = header.substring(PropertiesUtil.TOKEN_HEADER.length());

        JwtAuthenticationToken authRequest = new JwtAuthenticationToken(authToken);

        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }
```

Comment: The exception says **com.test.common.JwtTokenMissingException: No token found in request headers.**. This exception is thrown from within **your** attemptAuthentication method. It looks like you have to pass a JWT token most likely in the Authentication header. The JWT token is created by the authentication server.

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek Yes, I know that. What i am asking for is there anyway i can allow the permitAll to pass when the attemptAuthentication() is called or is there way i can control the order of validation when permitAll is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

permitAll means that any authentication, even `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` is allowed, however your request never makes it that far. You have a custom filter, I assume it is derived from `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, and since the filter throws an exception when the header is missing, you request never makes it to the `AuthenticationManager`!

There are several ways to solve this, here are two.

1. Create another filterchain `<sec:http...>` for endpoints that do not require a token, and use `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` for this filter chain.
2. Return `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` from your filter if the JWT header is missing.

Hope this helps.